# VB.Net: An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing. Unrecognised configuration section userSettings

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, reporting, rdlc, microsoft-reporting

I am having trouble with creating a report using the rdlc reports on visual studio in VB.Net. I keep getting this error message:

**"An error occurred during local report processing.
The definition of the report is invalid.
An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing.
Configuration system failed to initialise.
Unrecognised configuration section userSettings. (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Slnk\ManagementSystem.vshost.e_Url_brk155k23wwhtqesu2uousexuftu10hi\1.0.0.0\user.config file line 3**"

There doesn't seem to be any problems with my code because the error message does not point to my code, but points to the user.config file. I opened the file and this is the only thing displayed in the file:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
</configuration>
```

I searched for answers online, and tried deleting the user.config file and letting the application auto generate another one and it did not help. None of the solutions online have helped so far. Is there anyone who can please help me?

Answer (score 1):

So for anyone having this same problem, this is how I solved it. I went to the folder: 
**C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Slnk\ManagementSystem.vshost.e_Url_brk155k23wwhtqesu2uousexuftu10hi\1.0.0.0\user.config** and renamed the user.config file to xuser.config. Then I restarted my application and for some reason, it worked!!! Hope this helps to whomever ends up with this problem.

Comment: Didn't really work for me (I couldn't even find a file of that name), but it may work for someone....